# C# Regular Expression ends in _DXX where X is number

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression pattern in C# which allow you to have

next pattern: _DXX at the end of your  .

Example :

**04R5714A_D15** is correct

**04R5714A_D05** is incorrect

**04R5714A_D5** is correct

I tried :   `.*_D([1-9]{1}[0-9]?)` but it didn't work :

Comment: Please explain why the second example would be incorrect.

Comment: @PeterB because it starts with a 0

Comment: I just tried your pattern and it worked for me

Comment: Can you please put that in the question, and also try to make it more readable? I know not everybody knows perfect English,, but incomplete sentences + weird punctuation usually do not help in getting proper answers.

Comment: Why don't you clearly define the **rules** for what constitutes a valid pattern. Then it would be easier to define the pattern itself.

Answer (score 1):

`.*_D[1-9]\d?$` should work for you.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nXLK55/2)

`.*` catches everything up until your underscore

`_D` is a literal match

`[1-9]` matches one number in that range

`\d?` matches 0 or 1 single number (0-9)

`$` is the end of the string